# Get the prefix in Laravel 5.1 -Dingo/Api

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, dingo-api

I am using Laravel 5.1 and Dingo/Api. Is there a way to get the route prefix in it?
I tried the getLastGroupPrefix() but it always returns null

Here's my code

BaseController :

```
public function isAdminRequest()
    {
        return Route::getLastGroupPrefix();
    }
```

routes :

```
$api->group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function($api)
    {
        $api->resource('users', "App\Http\Controllers\UsersController");
    });
```

and I'm trying to use it in my UsersController by doing so

```
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->isAdminRequest();
    }
```

But I just get a blank page.

Comment: So you just want to get the prefix of the route? You want to return "admin"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the prefix of a group, change your function to look like this:

```
public function isAdminRequest(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    return $request->route()->getPrefix();
}
```

That will return "admin", as that is the prefix of the group.

Comment: How would I call that from my UsersController

Comment: @itsbharat ah, I see what you mean. Strictly speaking, controllers shouldn't talk to each other. Is there any reason you're not using the "isAdminRequest" inside of the UserController? Maybe if I understand your reasoning, I can help you better.

Comment: No UsersController extends BaseController. So I use the method like $this->isAdminRequest(). My problem with your solution is how do I pass a Request object as a argument to the function  (in GET)

Comment: I still don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve? I don't get why "isAdminRequest" is inside the BaseController?

Comment: BaseController just has this method isAdminRequest through which I can check in any Controller admin requests. I just want to know how to pass Request object in GET to the function that you have made?

Comment: Ok well your solution works perfectly fine with Illuminate/Http/Router..But fails in Dingo.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so for a temporary solution, I have done

```
public function isAdminRequest()
{
    $uri = Route::current()->uri();
    $uri = explode('/',$uri);
    if($uri[2] == "admin")
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I know pretty bad solution. But waiting for a better one. Till then. (If it's useful for anyone)